# Partial specialization and SFINAE

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following Matrix template class and there is a requirement to represent vector as either 1 x RowSize or ColSize x 1 matrix (so that I can reuse many matrix operators which are compatible with vectors: multiplying 2 matrices, multiplying matrix by a scalar etc):

```
template <class T, size_t ColumnSize, size_t RowSize>
struct Matrix {
    T [ColumnSize][RowSize];
}
```

I have two questions:

1) If I am not mistaken I can achieve that either by partial specialization or using SFINAE on Matrix methods (for example to enable 'length' method when either ColSize or RowSize is 1). What are the pros and cons of mentioned options?

2) If I choose to go with the partial specialization, is there a way to define one specialization for both row and column vectors, instead of this:

```
template <class T, size_t ColumnSize>
struct Matrix<T, ColumnSize, 1> {
    T length() const;

    T [ColumnSize][RowSize];
}

template <class T, size_t RowSize>
struct Matrix<T, 1, RowSize> {
    T length() const;

    T [ColumnSize][RowSize];
}
```

Comment: you should give more context, otherwise your question is "opinion-based".

Comment: If you asked for drawbacks and advantages of both, I think that would be better, since that is easier to answer objectively.

Comment: Recommendation: You could define the parameters as `template<class T, size_t Size, VectorOrientation orientation> class Matrix` with `enum class VectorOrientation { ColumnVector, RowVector };`. Then there would be no ambiguity I think.

Comment: Please, note that in C++ 2D arrays are row major, you should use `T [RowSize][ColumnSize];` or better a wrapper class upon a `std::array<T,RowSize*ColumnSize>`.

Comment: You can still have an `template<class T, size_t ColumnSize, size_t RowSize> using MatrixAlias = Matrix<T, ColumnSize * RowSize, ColumnSize == 1 ? ColumnVector : RowSize == 1 ? RowVector : (throw "one of row or column size must be 1")>;`

Comment: IMO you should clarify, whether your `Matrix` template (as the name indicates) should be usable as a generic matrix, and the vector functions are just additions for the vector special case. Or whether the template should *only* be usable as vectors.

Comment: I would split this up into 2 questions for 2 different versions. Once you know the most effective way to implement both, you will see which approach is "better", or be able to ask on codereview.

Comment: Matrix template must be usable and usable with vectors. Like multiplying 3 column and 2 row matrix with 1 column and 3 row matrix (column vector).

Comment: @Bob__ my understanding of C++ arrays is that it doesn't specify the "majorness". For example, if I have a M[3][4] matrix I can comprehend it as either a) matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns or b) matrix with 4 rows and 3 columns. What matters is how you traverse it, for a) case it is better to traverse it in a row major order and in the b) case it is better to traverse in a column major order (because of CPU cache access). Now if the matrix is kept in M[ColSize][RowSize] format, and in all algorithms where it is necessary to traverse, column major traversal is applied, it should be ok.

Comment: @VanushGrigoryan my understanding is that a-priori, the first number is the row, and the second is the column size, when specifying "int var[first][second]". Then, the majorness specifies what "var[i]" means. Does it specify the index into "first", or the index into "second"? The first would be a row-major system. The second would be a column-major system. Some language use column-major arrays.

Comment: @VanushGrigoryan So, you'll always consider this `int M[2][3] = {{1,2,3}{4,5,6}};` as a matrix with 2 columns and 3 rows ({1, 4}, {2, 5} and {3, 6}). As long as it's consistent all over your code and well documented I guess it shouldn't be a problem. As a personal note (emphasis on personal, not being a native english speaker myself), I find a variable name like `RowSize` a bit misleading, someone could interpret it as _"size of a row"_ (which, in a matrix, is the number of columns...), so I usually prefer `Rows` and `Columns`.

Comment: A matrix (2 indices) is a matrix and a vector (1 index) is a vector. A matrix with column or row number equal to 1 is still a matrix and not a vector. You should not abuse such a matrix as a vector, but instead have a separate vector class. Matrices with column or row number equal one should hardly ever feature.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether the requirement is "a general Matrix must not have a length method" (then SFINAE or inheritance should be used), or "`length` must not be called on a general Matrix" (then a static_assert inside of the `length` body is applicable). A third option is to not do anything and make `length` applicable on generic matrices, however there are still other operations that only work on vectors.

For "a general Matrix must not have a length method". To save space, I will use `int`, and shorter symbol names. Instead of `int_`, you should use `std::integral_constant`. The `int_` wrapper is needed because of language restrictions that forbid specializing with more complex computations if the parameter is a non-type parameter. Therefore we ḿake the paramer a type, and wrap the value into it. The following does not use SFINAE, but inheritance. With `d()` of the vector mixing base class, you can access the data of the vector at any time from within the mixing class.

```
template<int> struct int_;

template<typename D, typename S>
struct V { };

template<typename T, int A, int B>
struct M : V<M<T, A, B>, int_<A * B>> {
   T data[A][B];
};

template<typename T, int A, int B>
struct V<M<T, A, B>, int_<A + B - 1>> { 
   int length() const { return A * B; }

   M<T, A, B> *d() { return static_cast<M<T, A, B>*>(this); }
   const M<T, A, B> *d() const { return static_cast<const M<T, A, B>*>(this); }
};
```

This is now

```
int main() { 
   M<float, 1, 3> m1; m1.length();
   M<float, 3, 1> m2; m2.length();
   // M<float, 3, 2> m3; m3.length(); error
}
```

For "`length` must not be called on a general Matrix", you can use "static_assert"

```
template<typename T, int A, int B>
struct M {
   int length() const {
      static_assert(A == 1 || B == 1, "must not be called on a matrix!");
      return A * B;
   }

   T data[A][B];
};
```

Choose what is most appropriate

Answer (score 0):

SFINAE is only able to disable a template declaration based on its own parameters. It's a bit unnatural to disable a non-template member function such as `length`, using the parameters of the enclosing class. The technique looks like this:

```
template <class T, size_t RowSize, size_t ColumnSize>
struct Matrix {
    // SFINAE turns a non-template into a template.
    // Introduce a fake dependency so enable_if resolves upon function call.
    template< typename size_t_ = size_t >
    static constexpr
    // Now write the actual condition within the return type.
    std::enable_if_t< RowSize == 1 || ColumnSize == 1
    , size_t_ > length() const;
        { return RowSize * ColumnSize; }

    T [ColumnSize][RowSize];
}
```

If you can stomach this ugliness, then you get exactly what you want: a function of the desired type, which completely vanishes when the condition is not met. No other support is needed.

On the other hand, partial specialization affects the entire class definition. Since it's usually poor design to duplicate the entire class in each partial specialization, inheritance is used as Johannes describes.

Just to add one alternative to his answer, SFINAE can be used within partial specialization, to avoid the clever algebra and the `int_` issue.

```
// Add "typename = void" for idiomatic class SFINAE.
template<size_t RowSize, size_t ColumnSize, typename = void>
struct maybe_vector_interface { }; // Trivial specialization for non-vectors

// Partial specialization for vectors:
template<size_t RowSize, size_t ColumnSize>
struct maybe_vector_interface< RowSize, ColumnSize,
    std::enable_if_t< RowSize == 1 || ColumnSize == 1 > > { 
    static constexpr int length() const
        { return RowSize * ColumnSize; }
};

template<typename T, size_t RowSize, size_t ColumnSize>
struct Matrix
    : maybe_vector_interface<RowSize, ColumnSize> {
    T data[RowSize][ColumnSize];
};
```